# React native redux saga how to show error to user

Tags: react-native, error-handling, redux-saga

I am new to react native and react-saga. I have the api call working and as far as I can see everything is working as expected. But how do I display the error that I am getting from the server back to the user. Sorry if this is  a trivial question. here is my code so far

Containers/GetUserInfo.js

```
moveToJoinScreen(){
    this.props.getStudentAvator(vouchercode, DeviceInfo.getUniqueID(), 'iOS');
}

render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.moveToJoinScreen()}  underlayColor='#ff000000'>
          <Image style={styles.imagestyle} style={{height:60, width:150}} source={Images.joinNow} />
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          {'\n'}
        </Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.moveToRegisterScreen()}  underlayColor='#ff000000'>
            <Image style={styles.imagestyle} style={{height:80, width:150}} source={Images.registerMyId} />
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getStudentAvator:(emailaddress, deviceid, platform) => dispatch(StudentActions.SetupVoucherRequest(vouchercode, deviceid, platform))
})

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(LaunchScreen)
```

here is the saga.js

```
export function* SetupVoucherRequest(api, action) {
    const { vouchercode, deviceid, platform } = action
    if(vouchercode.length >11 || vouchercode.length < 10)
    {
        yield put(StudentCardActions.SetupVoucherFailuer())
        return
    }
    // make the call to the api
    const response = yield call(api.SetupVoucher, vouchercode, deviceid, platform)

    if (response.ok) {
        const firstUser = 'fahad'
        const avatar = 'Avatar_Fahad'
        // do data conversion here if needed
        yield put(StudentCardActions.SetupVoucherSuccess(avatar))
    } else {
        yield put(StudentCardActions.SetupVoucherFailuer())
    }
}
```

Not sure how I can pass the error back to the container page to display the error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you call `put(StudentCardActions.SetupVoucherFailuer())` you should update your state with the error and then pass the error to your ui via `mapStateToProps`

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  error: state.myStoreName.error,
  // depending on how your store is setup you might
  // have to use state.get('myStoreName').error
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LaunchScreen)
```

Now you can access the error in your ui via `this.props.error`

Comment: Is there anywhere I can read how to set  up the maStateToProps. Sorry still trying to learn all this stuff. Thanks

Comment: @user767018 https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux by Dan Abramov the inventor of Redux. `mapStateToProps` is in the `connect()` lessons but I suggest starting from the beginning.